# Python text adventure woes

Tags: python

```
if schoice == 1:
    print "You walk right up to the rat and proceed to BEAT THE SHIT OUT OF IT AHHHHHH. Ahem. Anyway, you look at your blood-covered fists and feel good about yourself. You know that you just leveled up your Unarmed to 11. BOOYA!"
    skills("Unarmed") = 11
else:
    "You proceed to be a little bitch and sneak past the rat. Even though you know that you are being a total coward, you feel good, and you know that you leveled up your sneak to 11. Oh Yeah!"
    skills("Sneak") = 11
```

First off, I would like to say that I have the `raw_input` stuff with everything else set up, but I was just wondering if I HAVE to split off from here, and then have to write the same thing a gazillion times, or I could make both of these choices, no matter which is picked, to proceed to a shared new choice?

Comment: You'll also have a problem because `skills("Unarmed") = 11` won't compile and yields `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`.

Comment: You probably meant `skills['Unarmed'] = 11`.

Comment: Yup, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to split everything every time there is a choice, no.

Consider this:

```
print('This happens first')
choice = raw_input('Make a choice (1 or 2)')
if choice == 1:
    print('Conditional event no1')
else:
    print('Conditional event no2')
print('This happens after the choice, no matter what happened')
```

The story can go on from there. You can visualize this as a flowchart resembling this:

```
                /------ Choice 1 -------\               
Starting point /                         \____ Happens in either case
               \                         /
                \------ Choice 2 -------/
```

Comment: This was pretty obvious I guess, but I just registered and wanted to test this out. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please accept this answer if this solved your problem :)